# How to change the text color of the selected row in material ui table

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, frontend

I am trying to change the color of the row text and the background color of row on selection.

I am able to change the background color successfully but I am not able to change the text color.

```
<TableRow
        className={classes.tableBody}
      >

tableBody: {
    "&:focus": {
      color: "yellow !important",
      backgroundColor: "#3D85D2 !important",
    },
  },
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @RyanCogswell : Added the code here https://codesandbox.io/s/o739857l3z. Thanks for looking into it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The background color is controlled in [`TableRow`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/TableRow/TableRow.js#L23). In order to get the correct specificity (you shouldn't ever need to leverage "!important" when overriding Material-UI styles), you need to leverage the "hover" class similar to what is done within `TableRow`.

The color is controlled in [`TableCell`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/TableCell/TableCell.js#L39), so that is the level where you need to control it.

For a working solution, in the styles you would have something like:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  tableRow: {
    "&$hover:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "blue"
    }
  },
  tableCell: {
    "$hover:hover &": {
      color: "pink"
    }
  },
  hover: {}
});
```

then in the rendering:

```
            <TableRow
              hover
              key={row.id}
              classes={{ hover: classes.hover }}
              className={classes.tableRow}
            >
              <TableCell
                className={classes.tableCell}
                component="th"
                scope="row"
              >
                {row.name}
              </TableCell>
```

Here's a working version based on your sandbox:

[image: Edit Table hover colors]

Here's a similar example, but using "selected" instead of "hover":

https://codesandbox.io/s/llyqqwmr79

This uses the following styles:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  tableRow: {
    "&$selected, &$selected:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "purple"
    }
  },
  tableCell: {
    "$selected &": {
      color: "yellow"
    }
  },
  selected: {}
});
```

and some state:

```
 const [selectedID, setSelectedID] = useState(null);
```

and changing the TableRow rendering to be:

```
            <TableRow
              hover
              key={row.id}
              onClick={() => {
                setSelectedID(row.id);
              }}
              selected={selectedID === row.id}
              classes={{ selected: classes.selected }}
              className={classes.tableRow}
            >
```

v4 of Material-UI will include [some changes](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/pull/15140) that should make overriding styles considerably easier (and easier to figure out how to do successfully without looking at the source code).

In v4 of Material-UI, we can use the global class names for the [selected state](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#pseudo-classes) ("Mui-selected") and for [TableCell](https://material-ui.com/api/table-cell/#css) ("MuiTableCell-root") and then we only need to apply a single class to TableRow:

```
const styles = (theme) => ({
  tableRow: {
    "&.Mui-selected, &.Mui-selected:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "purple",
      "& > .MuiTableCell-root": {
        color: "yellow"
      }
    }
  }
});
```

[image: Edit Table hover colors (forked)]

Comment: We are using the next version of material ui. Thanks

Comment: How are you setting focus to the row? In order to use focus, the rows need to be focus-able which they aren't by default. You might be better off leveraging the "selected" concept on the TableRow instead of using focus.

Comment: The "next" version won't include the changes I referenced until the next alpha or beta release occurs (there is generally a release every week) since it was just merged today.

Comment: Please refer to the sandbox code on how I used focus to change the color and background color on row selection. https://codesandbox.io/s/o739857l3z It does not work on the code here but on my project it does. I got help from the suggestion offered by @RyanCogswell. I tried using selected props that TableRow offers but it changes the style of all my rows, which I do not want. Thanks.

Comment: Can you send me a sandbox code that uses selected props. It is not working for me. It will be helpful. Thank you so much. Much appreciated.

Comment: I added an example to my answer using "selected".

Comment: How do you know the syntax for `"$selected &"` for the tableCell? The docs for `TableCell ` dont mention it - it is mentioned in `TableRow` but how are you supposed to know what properties 'higher up' will be respected by sub components?

Comment: could you also explain why `selected: {}` is required (which it is) - none of this appears particularly intuitive. i would have assumed from reading the docs that the  empty `selected` object should contain your css overrides

Comment: @wal Styles can't be applied directly within the `selected` CSS class because they wouldn't have high enough specificity. You can find this discussed some in the documentation here: https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#pseudo-classes. I've added an alternative solution at the end of my answer that leverages v4 aspects to use a slightly simpler syntax.

Answer (score 2):

This is the only solution that worked for me

```
const styles = theme => ({
  tableRow: {
   '&&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: '#0CB5F3',
    },
   },
});

   <TableRow
      hover
      className={classes.tableRow}
    >
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
 selected: {
    backgroundColor: "green !important",
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "green !important",
    },
  },
}));

 const classes = useStyles();
<TableRow selected classes={{selected: classes.selected,}}/>
```