# Material UI: manually highlight xgrid row

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am new to Material UI and React in general, but as a 10 yr HTML UI vet I am so perplexed right now. We are using `XGrid` component with rows and columns. When you hover over rows they highlight by turning light blue, but I am at a loss as to how this is happening. When I inspect the row with regular inspector, I don't see any class changes when hovering over the row. When I force hover state, it does not highlight the row. I am guessing two things

1. It's a mouseenter event, not hover
2. It's using some built in browser highlight, not a class

Anyway what I'm trying to do is manually highlight a row and it would make sense to use the same class/colour or call some API function, but I cannot find either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's documentation here: https://material-ui.com/api/table-row/

Here's an example: [How to change the text color of the selected row in material ui table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55852415/how-to-change-the-text-color-of-the-selected-row-in-material-ui-table)

Comment: Not trying to change the colour of a highlighted row. I wanted to manually trigger the highlight but can't even figure out how it's happening. The HTML does not change so no classes are being added.. I don't understand it.

Comment: You can just apply a className to one specific <Row> object. Just play with the styles using the example, and don't specify "hover". There are more examples in the docs - just click the code view marker (<>) and you can toggle between Javascript and Typescript:

https://material-ui.com/components/tables/#customized-tables

Comment: Ok I'll try that. Still curious how the colour is changing without any HTML changing.. !

Comment: There's a lot of transpiling going on under the hood and it all ends up as plain Javascript and HTML when it gets served up.

Comment: This looks like a neat demonstration: https://javascript.plainenglish.io/three-ways-to-use-babel-with-react-9faf3c0e846b

Comment: But it doesn't..! While watching a material ui row, and all its child elements, hovering over it changes its background colour but none of the HTML changes in inspector..

Comment: It does really! When I look here: https://material-ui.com/components/tables/#customized-tables

...if I open the Chrome dev console, and click and unclick the rows under "Sorting and Selecting" I see the <tr class="..."> className changes when I click or unclick, and the row color changes

Comment: Yes, I see click. But hover... hover my dude. I've been talking about hover this whole time..!!!

Comment: lol Well the hover is just part of static CSS that has a &hover on it. So the change is under the hood - the CSS is not changing, but the browser respects the conditional style.

Comment: Oh, duh. I feel old.

Comment: You and me both.